# Django registration is not working

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-urls, user-registration

I am trying to add a user registration page but its showing

```
NoReverseMatch at /register/
```

Here is my project urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('pages.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Pages urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

from django.contrib.auth import views

app_name = 'pages'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', home_view, name='home'),
    path('register/', register_user, name='register'),
]
```

Pages views.py

```
def home_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return render(request, 'home.html', {})

def register_user(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')

    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'register.html', context)
```

register.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Register</title>
</head>
<h2>Register here</h2>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'register' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}

        {% if form.errors %}
        <p>Invalid details</p>
        {% endif %}

        {{ form }}

        <input type="submit" value="Register">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

All is fine but still it's showing error

```
NoReverseMatch at /register/
Reverse for 'register' not found. 'register' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Comment: Since you added a namespace, it should be `{% url 'pages:register' %}`

Comment: Yes it works, and what if I didn't add a namespac?

Comment: Then it is just `{% url 'register' %}` (so then it would have worked the way you wrote it).

Comment: So you mean to say if I remove name='register' from  path('register/', register_user) then it would work

Comment: @BarsmanvapsFriend: no, if you remed `app_name = 'pages'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `urls.py` file, you specified a namespace:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

from django.contrib.auth import views

app_name = 'pages'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', home_view, name='home'),
    path('register/', register_user, name='register'),
]
```

This means that in order to *refer* to such named view, you need to prefix it with the namespace. So that means in the template you need to write it like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Register</title>
</head>
<h2>Register here</h2>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'pages:register' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}

        {% if form.errors %}
        <p>Invalid details</p>
        {% endif %}

        {{ form }}

        <input type="submit" value="Register">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Furthermore the `redirect(..)` should be rewritten the same way:

```
def register_user(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('pages:home')

    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'register.html', context)
```